# Prolog: Filtering a list?

Tags: list, filter, prolog, meta-predicate

I'm currently working on a very short project on Prolog, and just got stuck trying to apply a "filter" I have created to a list. I have what you could call the filter ready, but I can't apply it. It'd be better if I illustrate:

```
filter(A, B)
```

...outputs 'true' if certain conditions are met.

```
filterList(A, [X, Y, Z])
```

...outputs a list which includes all elements from the second argument that make the filter output **false**. (So if filter(A, X) is true, the output is [Y, Z] ).

I have the "filter" function ready, but now I need to apply it to a list as shown on the second example, excluding all elements for which the filter returns true when applied with the first argument.

So, if the filter is a simple A == B, the function is supposed to receive A [A,B,A,C,D,A] and output [B,C,D], having removed all the elements for which the filter applies, obviously.

I'm having trouble with the basic structure of the function, so if anyone could supply a basic outline for a function such as this it would be of great help. I've simplified my situation as much as possible so I can take whatever you may be able to provide and modify it for my needs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are searching for higher-order functions in Prolog, you should definetly consult [Naish (1995)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.35.4505), a very good resource on this.

His definition of `filter/3` is the following (he uses difference-list notation, therefore escapes having to define `filter/4`):

```
filter(_,[],[]).
filter(P, A0-As0, As) :-
    (
        call(P, A0) -> As = A0-As1
    ;
        As = As1
    )
    , filter(P, As0, As1).
```

I you have questions about this predicate, please ask me in the comment. Reading the paper is also highly recommended, it also definess `map`, `foldr` and `compose`! Note that many of the limitations he mentions (like, for example a missing `call/3` or a higher-order `apply` do not apply anymore. SWI-Prolog has the `=..` operator, which addresses all of his concerns and makes arbitrary n-order logic possible.

Comment: Pitty Naish proposes apply/3 in his conclusions, but I guess current way to go is to use call/n. apply/3 is simply call/3.

Comment: See for a discussion why Naish Reference is disputed: http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/naish.html

Answer (score 14):

SWI-Prolog offers `exclude/3` and other such meta-predicates. Your original problem can be coded like this:

```
are_identical(X, Y) :-
    X == Y.

filterList(A, In, Out) :-
    exclude(are_identical(A), In, Out).
```

Usage example:

```
?- filterList(A, [A, B, A, C, D, A], Out).
Out = [B, C, D].
```

Comment: include(<(5), [3,4,5,6,7], As). works the same as filter(<(5), [3,4,5,6,7], As).
exclude is the inverse in that it gives the same results as filter(>=(5), [3,4,5,6,7], As).

Comment: can be done without the are_identical rule.  replace filterList body with ---- exclude(=(A), In,Out)

Answer (score 4):

There is an inherent problem with filter functions that take the success or failure of a predicate as criterion for filtering: The resulting program is no longer a pure monotonic program. It therefore loses all its declarative properties — the only meaning that remains is a procedural step-by-step interpretation. Here is a pure, reified version of filtering using [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/772868):

```
tfilter(_CT_2,    [], []).
tfilter(CT_2, [E|Es], Fs0) :-
   if_(call(CT_2,E), Fs0 = [E|Fs], Fs0 = Fs ),
   tfilter(CT_2, Es, Fs).
```

The first argument is thus a closure/continuation that will receive two further arguments: The element and the resulting truth value.

```
=(X,X,true).
=(X,Y,false) :- dif(X,Y).
```

Now, results remain precise:

```
?- tfilter(=(X),[A,B],Xs).
   X = A, B = X, Xs = [X,X]
;  X = A, Xs = [X], dif(X,B)
;  X = B, Xs = [X], dif(X,A)
;  Xs = [], dif(X,A), dif(X,B).
```

There are four possibilities how a list of two elements can be filtered by the criterion of being equal to `X`. Each element might be equal or might be different.

The downside of this approach is that one has to provide reified versions of all criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Well what'd you know I just figured it out. So, here's me submitting an answer to my own question, as expected a really short function did the job:

```
filterList(_,[],R,R).           % Returns answer when the list is exhausted.
filterList(L,[A|List],Temp,Res) :-
   filterList(L,List,New,Res),  % Recursive call, New is either the same list
   (  filter(L,A),              % in case the filter outputs true, or the list
      New = Temp
   ;  New = [A|Temp]            % plus the current element otherwise.
   ).
```

Comment: This version always succeeds for any list. Intended?

Answer (score 0):

I get the adults of a country // Obtengo los adultos de un pais, Country = Pais, People = Personas, Person = una sola Persona

```
habitants(USA, [juan, pedro, david])

adults(Adults, Country) :-
     findall(Person, (habitants(Country,People), member(People, Person), adult(Person)), Adults)
```

This is a filter in prolog // Asi es un filter en prolog

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(_,[],[]).
filter(Predicate,[First|Rest],[First|Tail]) :-
   filter(Predicate,Rest,Tail).
filter(Predicate,[_|Rest],Result) :-
   filter(Predicate,Rest,Result).
```

Comment: How about including some sample queries demonstrating your proposed solution in action?