# Prolog - simple predicate - filter a list of pairs

Tags: prolog

I have a list of pairs (represent some locations in a matrix) and I like to filter the list to contain only locations at raw i.
this is what I wrote:

```
getRaw(_,[],[]).
getRaw(i,[(i,j)|LocationsTail],[(i,j)|result]) :-   
    getRaw(i,LocationsTail,result).
getRaw(i,[(k,t)|LocationsTail],result) :-
    i\=k,
    getRaw(i,LocationsTail,result).
```

This is what I wrote at the console:

```
1 ?- getRaw(1,[(1,2)],R).

false.
```

Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Variables in prolog must start with an upper case letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong: Variables start with a capital letter, you are using an incorrect version of negation.  Here is a clean approach:

First, define the precise condition you are after in a separate predicate:

```
fst_pair(X,(X,_)).
```

Then, try to define a more general predicate, that has its truth value as a separate argument:

```
fst_pair_truth(X,(X,_),true).
fst_pair_truth(X,(Y,_),false) :-
   dif(X,Y).
```

Note that the negative case is not simply the negation of the positive case: Both expect pairs.

Now, your definition is, maybe reconsider the name...

```
getRaw(I, Xs, Ys) :-
   tfilter(fst_pair_truth(I), Xs, Ys).
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297996/prolog-filtering-a-list/22053194#22053194) for a definition of `tfilter/3`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the lower case of the variables.
here is the fixed code:

```
getRaw(_,[],[]).
getRaw(Raw,[(Raw,Col)|LocationsTail],[(Raw,Col)|Result]) :- 
    getRaw(Raw,LocationsTail,Result).
getRaw(Raw,[(K,_)|LocationsTail],Result) :-
    Raw\=K,
    getRaw(Raw,LocationsTail,Result).
```

Comment: `?- getRaw(R,[(2,3)],[]).` fails, but there are values for `R` to make this succeed, like `R=1`. You need `dif/2` in place of `(\=)/2`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog-dif