# Remove element from a list by criteria with Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a list `L=[pt(0,0), pt(1,0), ecc..]`
I have a predicate `giveMeAngleBetween2Points/3` that gives me the angle between 2 points.
Now I need a predicate `deleteSameAnglePoints/2`that is like:

```
deleteSameAnglePoints(L, MinimumPoint)
```

where MinimumPoint is the point of the List L by my personal criteria, now I need to take my list L and delete all the points that have the same angle with MinimumPoint by calling predicate giveMeAngleBetween2Points(MinimumPoint, Point, Result), but taking the last one of them.

Example:

```
L = [(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,5), (3,4), (5,6), (5,8), (8,9), (10,9)]
```

Now, if `(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,5)` have the same angle with after calling predicate `giveMeAngleBetween2Points(MinimumPoint, Point)`, and also 
`(5,6), (5,8)` has the same angle between them, and also `(8,9), (10,9)` has the same angle between them, my result should be:

```
L = [(0,5), (3,4), (5,8), (10,9)].
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog: Filtering a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297996/prolog-filtering-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

could be

```
deleteSameAnglePoints([], []).
deleteSameAnglePoints([P|Ps], R) :-
    (  member(T, Ps), sameAngle(P, T)
    -> R = Q
    ;  R = [P|Q]
    ),
    deleteSameAnglePoints(Ps, Q).
```

where the service predicate sameAngle/2 has been defined - by means of your sample, as

```
sameAngle([(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,5)]).
sameAngle([(5,6), (5,8)]).
sameAngle([(8,9), (10,9)]).

sameAngle(A1,A2) :- sameAngle(L), memberchk(A1,L), memberchk(A2,L).
```

Comment: these are 'service' variables. T will scan every element after P. Q it's the result of the recursive call

Comment: @repeat: Pure version?