# Prolog: delete all spaces in list

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have list of lists like this:

```
[[q, ,w, ,e, ,r, ,t, ,z],[a, ,s, ,d, ,f, ,g, ,h],[y, ,x, ,c, ,v, ,b, ,n]]
```

and I need to delete all spaces except in last list.
So I want:

```
[[q,w,e,r,t,z],[a,s,d,f,g,h],[y, ,x, ,c, ,v, ,b, ,n]]
```

I tried:

```
deleteAll([_|[]],[]).
deleteAll([Head|Tail],L) :-
  deleteAll(Tail,_),
  subtract(Head,[ ],L).
```

But it doesnt work. I'm getting onlny:

```
[q, ,w, ,e, ,r, ,t, ,z]
```

So it seems that even *subtract*  didnt match the [ ] as space.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: How do you represent spaces? You need to write `' '`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
:- use_module(library(double_quotes)).

spdels([], []).
spdels([Cs], [Cs]).
spdels([Cs|Css], [Ds|Dss]) :-
   Css = [_|_],
   Dss = [_|_],
   text_nospaces(Cs, Ds),
   spdels(Css, Dss).

text_nospaces([], []).
text_nospaces([C|Cs], Ds0) :-
   if_(C = ' ', Ds0 = Ds1, Ds0 = [C|Ds1] ),
   text_nospaces(Cs, Ds1).


text_nospaces_bis(Cs, Ds) :-
   tfilter(dif(' '), Cs, Ds).
```

using [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600) and [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22053194/772868).

```
?- spdels(["a b c","d e","f g"], Cs).
   Cs = ["abc","de","f g"]
;  false.
```

Answer (score 3):

As @false already pointed out `[ ]` is not a space but the empty list. Also your predicate is describing `L` as `Head` minus the empty list, and it doesn't care about the result of the recursion (`deleteAll(Tail,_)`). That's why you get the unaltered first list as result.

Think about what the predicate should describe: a relation between two lists of lists where the second list contains the sublists of the first list without space, except the very last sublist, that is unaltered:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

lists_withoutspace([X],[X]).                    % last list unaltered
lists_withoutspace([H1,H2|T1],[H1WoS|T2]) :-    % H1Wos:
   list_withoutspace(H1,H1WoS),                 % first sublist without spaces
   lists_withoutspace([H2|T1],T2).              % the same for the rests
```

For list_withoutspace/2 you could use te built-in predicate char_type/2 to determine the type of the first list-element:

```
list_withoutspace([],[]).          % empty list contains no space
list_withoutspace([X|T],L) :-      % X is not in the list
   char_type(X,space),             % if it is space
   list_withoutspace(T,L).         % relation must also hold for tail
list_withoutspace([X|T],[X|L]) :-  % X is in the list
   char_type(X,alpha),             % if it is a letter
   list_withoutspace(T,L).         % relation must also hold for tail
```

If you want to match more than letters change `alpha` accordingly. If you query this predicate, you get the desired result:

```
   ?- lists_withoutspace([[q,' ',w,' ',e,' ',r,' ',t,' ',z],[a,' ',s,' ',d,' ',f,' ',g,' ',h],[y,' ',x,' ',c,' ',v,' ',b,' ',n]],L).
L = [[q,w,e,r,t,z],[a,s,d,f,g,h],[y,' ',x,' ',c,' ',v,' ',b,' ',n]] ? ;
no
```

Or more compactly:

```
   ?- lists_withoutspace(["q w e r t z","a s d f g h","y x c v b n"],L).
L = [[q,w,e,r,t,z],[a,s,d,f,g,h],[y,' ',x,' ',c,' ',v,' ',b,' ',n]] ? ;
no
```

Comment: s(X). Bonus question: how can I find out / test automatically (without reading all the documentation) which built-in / library predicates are pure enough for my taste?

Comment: @repeat: I'd probably try the two characterisations in the tag-info of [tag:logical-purity]. In this case char_type/2 (I assume that's the built-in you refer to) succeeds if one argument is instantiated but the generalisation, the most general query, leads to an instantiation error. However, the way I use it the second argument is always `space` and using it that way doesn't break commutativity of conjunction, e.g. `?- X=' ', char_type(X,space).` and `?- char_type(X,space), X=' '.` yield the same result. In this case that's good enough for me.

Comment: Thx 4 Ur reply! Sounds good to me... just wondering how to check this out automatically, to aid the programmer / coder / user / myself with seeing the boundaries between the pure and impure.

Comment: It's high time to implement `predicate_algebraicproperties/2` ;)  maybe with a little help using annotations like "I promise `memberd/2` is pure"... what's your take on this?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, we should make it. Seriously! The way I see it: (1) both pure and impure code could profit, (2) it would fit nicely with meta-predicates (e.g., `maplist/3` is pure if its first arg is pure), (3) we could only win, because of "lowered expectations", (4) it burns a lot of processor cycles and hopefully points to some insights.

Answer (score 3):

Why not delegate the "recursive part" to Prolog library predicates?

Based on [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490900/delete-vowels-in-a-list/29963476) and 
[`dif/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990728/most-general-higher-order-constraint-describing-a-sequence-of-integers-ordered-w/29867514) define `spaces_gone/2` like so:

```
:- use_module(library(lists), [same_length/2, reverse/2, maplist/3]).

spaces_gone([], []).
spaces_gone([A|As], [D|Ds]) :-
   same_length(As, Ds),
   reverse([A|As], [Last|Bs]),
   maplist(tfilter(dif(' ')), Bs, Cs),
   reverse([Last|Cs], [D|Ds]).
```

Sample query using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2:

```
| ?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars),
     use_module(library(double_quotes)).
% ...
yes

| ?- spaces_gone(["a b c","d e","f g"], Css).
Css = ["abc","de","f g"] ? ;
no
```

Answer (score 0):

code :

```
deleteAllSpaces_except_last([X],[X]):-!.                % without last Element

deleteAllSpaces_except_last([[]|Ys],[[]|Ys1]):-         % End of List inside List_of_lists
        deleteAllSpaces_except_last(Ys,Ys1).

deleteAllSpaces_except_last([[X|Xs]|Ys],Res):-          % if X=' ' then skip else add into New list inside list_of_lists
        (X=' ',Res=[Xs1|Ys1];Res=[[X|Xs1]|Ys1]),
        deleteAllSpaces_except_last([Xs|Ys],[Xs1|Ys1]).
```

test :

```
| ?- deleteAllSpaces_except_last([[q,' ',w,' ',e,' ',r,' ',t,' ',z],[a,' ',s,' ',d,' ',f,' ',g,' ',h],[y,' ',x,' ',c,' ',v,' ',b,' ',n]],L).
L = [[q,w,e,r,t,z],[a,s,d,f,g,h],[y,' ',x,' ',c,' ',v,' ',b,' ',n]] ? ;
no

| ?- deleteAllSpaces_except_last([[q,' ',w,' ',e,' ',r,' ',t,' '],[],[y,' ',x,' ',c,' ',v,' ',b,' ',n]],L).
L = [[q,w,e,r,t],[],[y,' ',x,' ',c,' ',v,' ',b,' ',n]] ?
```

Comment: `deleteAllSpaces_except_last([[C],[]], Xs).` should give two answers

Comment: @false  I added `deleteAllSpaces_except_last([[]],[]).` ?

Comment: `X = a, deleteAllSpaces_except_last([[X],[]],[[X],[]]).` correctly succeeds, but the same without `X = a` fails.

Comment: @false how I can fix it ?

Comment: `X = ' ' -> `... commits too early.

Comment: The goal `deleteAllSpaces_exceipt_last(["A B",""], ["A B",""]).`. It should fail. Put the blame on `(X=' ',Res=[Xs1|Ys1];Res=[[X|Xs1]|Ys1])` which is missing some `dif/2` goal...