# How to combine list operations?

Tags: prolog

I would like to count how often element x is in list L.

I know there is a way with recursion, but is it also possible like this:

```
> count(X,L,C) = C is (length(L,Length) - length(delete(L, X,
> List2),Length)).
?
```

The compiler say no:) What could I change?

Comment: Does `delete` delete *all* occurrances of the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, since `length(L, Length)` is not a function. It is a predicate, so it is `True` or `False` (or gets stuck in an infinite loop, or errors, but you can argue that these are not really "results" of a predicate).

Furthermore, you can not call a predicate like `length(delete(L, X, List2), Length)`, since, for the Prolog interpreter, the `delete/3` is here just a *functor*. It will thus not *call* the `delete/3` predicate.

You can however rewrite this to:

```
count(X, L, C) :-
    length(L, N1),
    delete(L, X, L2),
    length(L2, N2),
    C is N1 - N2.
```

Comment: @katarina: Note that `X = b, count(X,[a,a],0).` correctly succeeds, yet, `count(X,[a,a],0), X = b.` fails. Thus, this definition is not a relation. A definition that succeeds for both is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44377914/772868).