# How to filter in Prolog with SWISH

Tags: list, prolog, filtering

I need to make a predicate called *fAtomPairs* so that given an atom (first argument), and a list of pairs (each pair is in turn a list of two atoms), unify a third parameter with the *filtered* list of pairs by selecting only those pairs that have as their first component the atom which is the first argument.

For example :

```
fAtomPairs(sA,[[basA,absAb],[ab,bbsA],[sA,abbsB],[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]],X)
```

must result in

```
X = [[sA,abbsB],[sA,bb]]
```

How can I do this?, I'm currently working in [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:- use_module(library(reif)).   % SICStus|SWI
:- use_module(library(lambda)). % SICStus|SWI

fAtomPairs(Sel, DEs, Es) :-
   tfilter(\[A,_]^ ( Sel = A ), DEs, Es).
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, but you can not use those libraries directly in Swish by just saying ` :- use_module(library(reif)). `

Comment: You can use `library(reif)` in SWISH (not immediately obvious).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a version of [tfilter/3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297996/prolog-filtering-a-list) and [if_/3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358456/prolog-union-for-a-u-b-u-c/27358600#27358600). 
I also changed the representation from lists of two elements to pairs.

```
fAtomPairs(sA,[basA-absAb,ab-bbsA,sA-abbsB,bsA-sAsB,sA-bb]).


tfilter(_CT_2,    [], []).
tfilter(CT_2, [E-Thing|Es], Fs0) :-
   if_(call(CT_2,E), Fs0 = [E-Thing|Fs], Fs0 = Fs ),
   tfilter(CT_2, Es, Fs).

=(X,X,true).
=(X,Y,false) :- dif(X,Y).


if_(If_1, Then_0, Else_0) :-
   call(If_1, T),
   (  T == true -> call(Then_0)
   ;  T == false -> call(Else_0)
   ;  nonvar(T) -> throw(error(type_error(boolean,T),_))
   ;  /* var(T) */ throw(error(instantiation_error,_))
   ).
```

Then query:

```
?-fAtomPairs(SA,Pairs),tfilter(=(SA),Pairs,Filtered).
Filtered = [sA-abbsB, sA-bb],
Pairs = [basA-absAb, ab-bbsA, sA-abbsB, bsA-sAsB, sA-bb],
SA = sA
false
```

Comment: what does "CT" in `CT_2` stand for, please? (and "_2", for that matter.)

Comment: Its copied from the answer by false that I linked.. I believe it stands for closure/continuation and the fact it will take two arguments.

Comment: thanks. I thought C was for "callable", but what's T?.. something to do with "truth"?..

Comment: yea I think it is for truth.

Comment: @WillNess: continuation, criterion.

Comment: @user27815: Why do you change `tfilter/3`? — user another name.